# Excel CountIf Formula With OR

Tags: excel

I was looking for a excel formula to do a task. Tried using Countif,Countifs. But with no luck. Any help is appreciated.
Task as below.

Type--------------Primary Color--------------Secondary Color
Car----------------Blue--------------------------Red
Bike--------------Black-------------------------White
Car---------------Blue--------------------------Blue

I need a formula which gives me a count of Cars having blue as their colour(Either Primary Or Secondary)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` to calculate count of blue cars:

```
=SUM(N((B2:B4="Blue")+(C2:C4="Blue")>0)*(A2:A4="Car"))
```

or non array version:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N((B2:B4="Blue")+(C2:C4="Blue")>0)*(A2:A4="Car"))
```

This part:

```
(B2:B4="Blue")+(C2:C4="Blue")>0
```

is an alternative way of expressing `OR` (not suitable for array formulas as it always returns a single value). `N` function converts boolean values to `0` and `1`.

**Edit:** updated the formulas to include condition for `A` column.

Comment: I would drop the row numbers here as I believe OP doesn't wan't to have to continually edit the formula as the length of the data set changes. VBA would also be a viable solution, but I don't know if that is an option.

Comment: @MattCremeens using full column references would decrease performance. It's posssible to define dynamic ranges for `A:C` columns, but it's not a part of the question.

Comment: I know it was not part of the original question, but I'm learning that there are requirements not a part of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a column with the following

```
=IF(OR(B1="Blue", C1="Blue"), 1, 0)
```

and copy that down.

On another sheet you can sum that new entire column with

```
=SUM(D:D)
```

Of course you will have a worksheet reference to the other sheet attached to the `SUM` formula.

Comment: That can definitely be done. But I wanted the total count to be pulled in another sheet, which is the dashboard. A single formula is much preferred.

Comment: Then you could link to the sum from the other sheet.

Comment: But the last row keeps varying. So linking everytime would be a pain. So a single formula in dashboard which picks the count irrespective of the data last row will be much helpful

Comment: See my edit on how to sum an entire column, so if it grows or shrinks in length, it won't matter.

Comment: If the result can be achieved using SUMPRODUCT formula it would be better because the actual data sheet will be updated by a team and we cannot ask them to drap and drop the formulas.

Comment: Maybe try `=SUM(IF(B:B="Blue",1,IF(C:C="Blue",1,0),0))` and hit `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` while in the cell.

Comment: There is another condition. A:A has to be CAR. In simple words, I want count of blue cars

Comment: Then modify to `=SUM(IF(A:A="Car", IF(B:B="Blue", 1, IF(C:C="Blue",1, 0), 0), 0))`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do an array formula you can just do 2 countifs formulas (which are easier for people to read than array formulas)

```
=COUNTIFS(b8:b12,"Blue")+COUNTIFS(c8:c12,"Blue")
```

Comment: That would give you an incorrect count of 3 because it would count the car with blue as both the primary and secondary color twice. Now you could do something like `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"Car",B2:B10,"Blue")+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"Car",C2:C10,"Blue")-COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"Car",B2:B10,"Blue",C2:C10,"Blue")` which counts the number of cars with blue as the primary, then adds the number of cars with blue as the secondary, then corrects by subtracting the number cars that have blue as both primary AND secondary.